# Adding Shader node to Material - Cannot see it - Python

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

This is my code from the some operator: (simplified)

```
def b(obj):
  mat = obj.data.materials[0]
  nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
  image = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage') 
  image.name = "MyImage"
  #here i created a new image node, i can access and change any of its values:
  #this also gives no issues:
  obj.data.materials[0].node_tree.nodes['MyImage']

def a():
  b(obj)
  #gives no issues:
  obj.data.materials[0].node_tree.nodes['MyImage']
  # -> i cannot see this node

a()
```

I create an image node inside `b()` and work with its settings there and then use inside `a()`

The console doesn't show any errors, but when i look into shader editor, there is no image node created,

And it doesn't work even if i write all the code in a singe function

but if i loop through all the nodes and try to find the image node, it says that it exists

Comment: The code as currently written does not work, because the `obj` variable is not defined. Other than that, the script works. It creates an Image Texture node in the first material. Perhaps you are not looking at the first material or the wrong object in the shader editor?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the obj is defined (i just didn't write it here) and the material is also correct, I tested this code in the blender scripting tab, and it works. But I use it when operator executes, a() is called but after the operator finished execution, I cannot see the image node in the material. The console doesn't give any errors

Comment: Then please provide the full code you're trying to run, because the issue is not in the snippet you've provided. If you test your example from the question with `obj` set to `bpy.context.object` you will see that it works as intended.

Comment: Probably the act of redacting your code for this question also fixed the issue. Maybe the issue is related to scope, like name shadowing.

Comment: I fixed the issue: it's strange but if I remove `image.name = "MyImage"` line everything works - I can see the node in the ShaderEditor. Idk why it's like this

Comment: Perhaps there's another node with the same name, which is renamed due to naming collision?

Comment: I thought the same, but when I looped through all the nodes before adding "MyImage" there was no with such name. Strange, thanks though